# how to exit a child process - _exit() vs. exit

Tags: c, process, fork

Consider this code snippet:

```
pid_t cpid = fork();

if (cpid == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (cpid == 0) { // in child
    execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
    perror("execvp");
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// in parent
```

How shall I exit the child process if execvp returns? Shall I use exit() or _exit()?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should definitely use `_Exit()`.  `exit()` calls the functions you added with `atexit()` and deletes files created with `tmpfile()`.  Since the parent process is really the one that wants these things done when it exists, you should call `_Exit()`, which does none of these.

Notice `_Exit()` with a capital E.  `_exit(2)` is probably not what you want to call directly.  `exit(3)` and `_Exit(3)` will call this for you.  If you don't have `_Exit(3)`, then yes, `_exit()` is what you wanted.

Comment: +1 You want the failed child process to exit quietly as if it had never been created.

Comment: Well since the old C standard allowed the linker to resolve case insensitive _Exit() cannot be a standard library function as it would conflict with the older _exit(). Sorry.

Comment: On the contrary.  _Exit(3) is a standard C library (ISO C99).  _exit(2) is a POSIX.1 system call and not a C standard.

Comment: Whether open resources such as files are closed after calling `_Exit` is implementation defined. You probably do not want this behaviour (regarding unflushed streams).

All man pages I have seen say that `_exit` does not flush streams, so it is safer if a file has unflushed content when forking happens. The fact that `_exit` is not standard C is a moot point, as `fork` is Unix-specific too. The C standard committee may have special reasons to introduce `_Exit`, but there is no reason for Unix programmers to change `_exit` to `_Exit` at all. @VariableLengthCoder

Answer (score 18):

The child of fork() should always call _exit().

Calling exit() instead is a good way to cause pending stdio buffers to be flushed twice.

Comment: exec doesn't return except in error, in which you call _exit.

Answer (score 3):

execvp will exit the child if successfull so you don't have to exit.

On execve failure I simply use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` in the child.

Edit : i found that after some research : http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/1.1.3.shtml

So it's looks like it's better to use `_exit()` in a fork child specially when you are in C++ :p
Thanks for your question i learned something :D

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the behavior you want: `man -s 3 exit` and `man _exit` for more details on your system. In general I believe the _exit doesn't run functions that are registered with atexit() whereas exit does (these functions better not call exit - otherwise you get recursion).

In general I would prefer exit over _exit except for in functions registered with atexit, in those I would call _exit, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`exit()` is ANSI-C function and therefore, it is operating system independent. It closes all ANSI-C standard functions.
`_exit()` is called by `exit()` to close operating system-dependent functionalities, because `exit()` has no idea about them.(`exit` is operating system independent)

Comment: "_exit() is a Linux Kernel function" is not correct, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html

Comment: You are right about that, but the rest of my comment is true. See: Unix Systems Programming by David Curry, page 291.