# exit() or _exit() after forking?

Tags: c++, fork, exit

I am writing a program which requires communicating with an external program two-way simultaneously, i.e., reading and writing to an external program at the same time.

I create two pipes, one for sending data to the external process, one for receiving data from the external process. After forking the child process, which becomes the external program, the parent forks again. The new child now writes data into the outgoing pipe to the external program, and the parent now reads data from the incoming pipe from the external program for further processing.

I've heard that using exit(3) may cause buffers to be flushed twice, however I am also afraid that using _exit(2) may leave buffers left unflushed. In my program, there are outputs both before and after forking. Which, exit(3) or _exit(2), should I use in this case?

The below is my main function. The #includes and auxiliary function is left out for simplicity.

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    ssize_t n;
    cin >> n;
    for (double p = 0.0; p <= 1.0; p += 0.1) {
        string s = generate(n, p);
        int out_fd[2];
        int in_fd[2];
        pipe(out_fd);
        pipe(in_fd);
        pid_t child = fork();
        if (child) {
            // parent
            close(out_fd[0]);
            close(in_fd[1]);
            if (fork()) {
                close(out_fd[1]);
                ssize_t size = 0;
                const ssize_t block_size = 1048576;
                char buf[block_size];
                ssize_t n_read;
                while ((n_read = read(in_fd[0], buf, block_size)) != 0) {
                    size += n_read;
                }
                size += n_read;
                close(in_fd[0]);
                cout << "p = " << p << "; compress ratio = " << double(size) / double(n) << '\n'; // data written before forking (the loop continues to fork)
            } else {
                write(out_fd[1], s.data(), s.size()); // data written after forking
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // exit(3) or _exit(2) ?
            }
        } else {
            // child
            close(in_fd[0]);
            close(out_fd[1]);
            dup2(out_fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(in_fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(STDERR_FILENO);
            execlp("xz", "xz", "-9", "--format=raw", reinterpret_cast<char *>(NULL));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to exit a child process - \_exit() vs. exit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329640/how-to-exit-a-child-process-exit-vs-exit)

Comment: @hvd: No, I don't think so. The linked duplicate is about handling errors. This case does not seem to be about errors (although the error handling in the child process seems to be a bit lacking...

Comment: @MatsPetersson I don't see how that other question is about handling errors, can you elaborate? At any rate, I think the points made in the accepted answer there apply here.

Comment: Ok, it's about "what do you do when some form of exec returns", which is an error condition, since "exec" will replace the existing process. This one is more complicated, because there is output going on in a child process that is still executing as a forked process. You can't just use `_exit()` either in that case.

Comment: @MatsPetersson That other question has output going on in a child process too: it calls `perror`. Yes, the output happens in an error condition in that question, and not in an error condition in this one, but I don't see how that makes any difference. All the implementation knows is that output is written, it doesn't know and has no way of knowing whether it's an error condition. (In fact, depending on the specific `exec`, the programmer might have no way of knowing whether it's an error condition either!)

Comment: "You want the failed child process to exit quietly as if it had never been created." - this is clearly not the case when you have done intentional output in the main process. And if the `perror` was a `printf`, I expect no output would be produced, which is perhaps not the wanted effect. The fact that `stderr` is unbuffered helps here...

Comment: @MatsPetersson That is a comment on the answer there, not the question itself, not the answer itself. But your remark about `printf` is a good point.

Answer (score 1):

In the child branch of a fork(), it is normally incorrect to use exit(), because that can lead to stdio buffers being flushed twice, and temporary files being unexpectedly removed. In C++ code the situation is worse, because destructors for static objects may be run incorrectly. (There are some unusual cases, like daemons, where the parent should call _exit() rather than the child; the basic rule, applicable in the overwhelming majority of cases, is that exit() should be called only once for each entry into main.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with these sort of things. `exit()` does different things to `_exit()` and yet again different to `_Exit()`, and as the answer suggested as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329640/how-to-exit-a-child-process-exit-vs-exit?rq=1) explains, the `_Exit` (not same as `_exit`, note upper case E) will not call `atexit()` handlers, or flush any output buffers, delete temporary files, etc [which may in fact be `atexit()` handling, but it could also be done as a direct call, depending on how the C library code has been written].

Most of your output is done via `write`, which should be unbuffered from the applications perspective. But you are calling `cout << ...` as well. You will need to make sure that is flushed before exiting. Right now, you are using `'\n'` as the end of line marker, which may or may not flush the output. If you change that to `endl` instead, it will flush the file. Now you can safely use `_Exit()` from an output perspective - if your code were to set up its own `atexit()` handler for example, open temporary files or a bunch of other such things, this would be problematic. If you want to do more complex things in the forked process, it should be done by another `exec`.

In your program as it stands, there isn't any pending output to flush, so it "works" anyway, but if you add a `cout << ... << '\n';` (or without the newline) type statement at the beginning of the code, you would see it go wrong. If you add a `cout.flush();`, it would "fix" the problem (based on your current code).

You should also check the return value from your `execlp()` call and call `_Exit()` in that case (and handle it in the main process so you don't continue the loop in case of failure?)

Comment: My code is intended for internal use only (it's not application code), so I left out error checking for simplicity. However, it is crucial for my code to output exactly the things I intend to do so, since it would be parsed by external programs.