# Program output changes when piped

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have a simple C program to time process startup (I'd rather not post the full code as it's an active school assignment). My main function looks like this:

```
int main(void) {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%lf\n", sample_time());
  }

  exit(0);
}
```

`sample_time()` is a function that times how long it takes to fork a new process and returns the result in seconds as a `double`. The part of `sample_time()` that forks:

```
double sample_time() {
  // timing stuff

  if (!fork()) exit(0); // immediately close new process

  // timing stuff

  return a_sample_time;
}
```

As expected, running the program, `times`, in the terminal outputs 5 numbers like so:

```
$ ./times
0.000085
0.000075
0.000079
0.000071
0.000078
```

However, trying to redirect this into a file (or anywhere else) in a Unix terminal produces unexpected results.

For example, `./times > times.out` creates a file with fifteen numbers. Additionally, `./times | wc -l` outputs `15`, confirming the earlier result. Running `./times | cat`, I again see fifteen numbers, <strike>more than five of which are distinct</strike>.

Does anyone know what on earth can cause something like this? I'm out of ideas.

`./times` != `./times | cat`. Wat.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Prerequisite knowledge

- **Fact 1** - When stdout is connected to a TTY it is line buffered. When it's connected to a file or a pipeline it is full buffered. This means it's only flushed [every 8KB, say](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html#index-BUFSIZ-1147), rather than every line.
- **Fact 2** - Forked processes have duplicate copies of in-memory data. This includes stdio's output buffers if the data hasn't been flushed yet.
- **Fact 3** - Calling `exit()` causes stdio's output buffers to be flushed before the program exits.

#### Case 1: Output to terminal

When your program prints to the terminal its output is line buffered. Each `printf()` call that ends with `\n` immediately prints. This means each line is printed and the in-memory output buffer is emptied before `fork()` runs.

**Result**: 5 lines of output.

#### Case 2: Output to pipeline or file

When libc sees that stdout isn't connected to a TTY it switches to a more efficient full buffering strategy. This causes output to be buffered until 4KB worth have accumulated. That means the output from the `printf()`s is saved in memory, and calls to `write()` are deferred.

```
if (!fork()) exit(0);
```

After forking, the child process has a copy of the buffered output. The `exit()` call then causes that buffer to be flushed. This doesn't affect the parent process, though. Its output is **still buffered**.

Then when the second line of output is printed, it has two lines buffered. The next child process forks, exits, and prints those two lines. The parent retains its two lines of output, and so on.

**Result:** The child processes print 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 lines of output. The main program prints 5 when it finally exits and flushes its output. 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15. 15 lines of output instead of 5!

#### Solutions

1. [Call `_Exit()` instead of `exit()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329640/how-to-exit-a-child-process-exit-vs-exit). The function `_Exit()` is like `exit()`, but does not call any functions registered with `atexit()`. This would be my preferred solution.
2. Explicitly set stdout to be line buffered: `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);`
3. Call `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf`.