# How to exit child process correctly?

Tags: c, fork

With this code example I expect that my child processes will exit normally:

```
int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        int pid = fork();
        printf("pid %d\n", pid);
        sleep(1);
        if (pid == 0)
            exit(0);
    }
}
```

But when I run `ps`, I get the following output:

```
5089 pts/0    00:00:00 test
5090 pts/0    00:00:00 test <defunct>
5091 pts/0    00:00:00 test <defunct>
5092 pts/0    00:00:00 test <defunct>
5094 pts/0    00:00:00 test <defunct>
```

What should I do to make child process exit normally?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329754/3835843 it might be help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent process must call one of the `wait` functions (wait, waitpid, waitid, wait4), to release child process resources. See then manpage of waitpid:

```
WAIT(2)

NAME
       wait, waitpid, waitid - wait for process to change state

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/wait.h>

       pid_t wait(int *wstatus);

       pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *wstatus, int options);

       int waitid(idtype_t idtype, id_t id, siginfo_t *infop, int options);
                       /* This is the glibc and POSIX interface; see
                          NOTES for information on the raw system call. */

   Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       waitid():
           Since glibc 2.26: _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 ||
               _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
           Glibc 2.25 and earlier:
               _XOPEN_SOURCE
                   || /* Since glibc 2.12: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
                   || /* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ _BSD_SOURCE

DESCRIPTION

…

       In the case of a terminated child, performing a wait
       allows the system to release the resources associated with the child;
       if a wait is not performed, then the terminated child remains in a
       "zombie" state (see NOTES below).
```

Comment: Is there a way not to wait? I dont want my parent process to wait because in real code It must go on and child processes must go on too, they may not finish for a long time

Comment: wait just before exiting

Comment: What should I do if parent process is spawning lots of children, some of them have became zombies and some haven't? How can I clear zombies, but not waiting other children to exit?

Comment: @Sanya As I wrote in my answer, just have the parent process exit. That will clean up everything.

Comment: That doesn't help for a long-running parent such as a demon

Comment: @Sanya: Install a `SIGCHLD` signal handler and do the `wait` in there (the `wait` family of functions is safe to call in a signal handler). Contrary, to what the name may suggest, `wait` doesn't cause a delay at all, if there are already `<defunct>` child processes around.

Answer (score 1):

If `wait` is not called by the parent and then the child terminates - then it (child) remains a zombie - waiting indefinitely for its exit status to be reaped. And this is the case happening in your case.

If you donot want to call wait in your parent, then you must create your child as a detached process.  `daemon()` ***might*** help you. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html

Comment: +1 for mentioning the daemon concept, but the proposed function is not really the best solution (read the docs you provided thoroughly).

Answer (score 1):

Your processes have exited normally. `<defunct>` means the process is dead and the only thing that's left is its PID and its exit status.

To clean up these `<defunct>` entries in the process table, the parent process must either `wait()` for its children or exit itself. In the latter case (parent process dies), the child processes become orphans and are adopted by `init` (the process with PID 1), which cleans up after them.

On some systems<sup>1</sup> you can also ignore the `SIGCHLD` signal:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

This means child processes will be reaped immediately.

---

<sup>1</sup> POSIX [lists this feature](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html#tag_16_01_03_01) as an XSI extension. While not required for POSIX conformance, it will be supported by all [XSI conforming](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html#tag_02_01_04) systems.